# Process spawned by tomcat7 pauses

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jruby, delayed-job

I have simple `ServletContextListener` that runs a process when tomcat starts and shuts it down when tomcat shuts down.

Process:

```
java -jar application.war -S rake jobs:work
```

It spawns a ruby `delayed_job` worker that processes queues. However problem arises when there are lots of jobs to process or a job takes a while. It processes a few and then It just stops. No errors are thrown, nothing in the log. It just halts execution.

When I restart the server, an entry gets put in the log that shutdown signal was sent. Worker wakes up, finishes a job (if it was paused during execution) and exits.

When I run that command outside of tomcat7, it works fine as expected.

`ServletContextListener` code:

```
public class RakeServlet implements ServletContextListener
{
  private Process workerProcess;

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
  {
    workerProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar application.war -S rake jobs:work");
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
  {
    workerProcess.destroy();
  }
}
```

`ps aux` output:

```
tomcat7   2119  0.5 16.9 3479300 668704 ?      Sl   02:20   2:41 java -jar application.war -S rake jobs:wor
```

Comment: If you run it from the command line instead of from tomcat, what's printed to the console when processing stops?

Comment: @Sam if i run it from command line then processing does not stop

Comment: Sorry I should have read that more carefully. It's possible you need to read the write the input / read the output streams your application uses as not doing so can cause it to hang. Can you use tomcat to load the war file directly and avoid the Runtime call?

Comment: hmmm, I can take a look at faking io. It does load the war file directly. But I also want a separate process for running background tasks. Not sure if this was the best way to go about it

Comment: I mean putting this servlet inside the war file and putting it in the webapps directory, then calling whatever your main() does with your arguments. Runnable war files are a bit non standard, and you lose lots of debugging context with the indirection when running it via Runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when running an external process you *must* read both the `stdout` and `stderr` streams from the child process. Otherwise, when the output buffers fill up, the process effectively gets paused on an I/O write block.

In order to do this properly, you'll need to start some threads to monitor those streams and empty them (presumably, doing something useful with the output and not simply discarding it).

For more details, have a look at [Steve Liles's blog post on the subject](http://steveliles.github.io/invoking_processes_from_java.html) where he describes the problem and examples for the solution.

If the target process will actually be another Java process, you ought to consider running the Java code in-process to avoid the overhead of launching a second JVM and the complexities of communicating with it (i.e. the stdio streams).

Comment: Is it possible to detach that process all together?

Comment: @Ruslan Do you mean similar to "backgrounding" a process from a shell? No, I don't believe there is a way to do that from within Java. The stream buffers will always be a problem. I know of no way from within Java to re-map those streams to e.g. native file descriptors that are already open.